# Check if there a string in a column containing numbers

Tags: python

In the below example, last column (c) contains random string called 'new' . So is there way to check if a columns contains a string (Need not be only 'new'. it could be any string)

```
df_sam = pd.DataFrame({
        'a' : ['rick','johnatthan','katei','diana','richard'],
        'b' : ['rich','roman','italy','ed','taylor'],
        'c' : [2,3,4,5,'new']
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can give you an idea ,

```
import pandas as pd
df_sam = pd.DataFrame({
        'a' : ['rick','johnatthan','katei','diana','richard'],
        'b' : ['rich','roman','italy','ed','taylor'],
        'c' : [2,3,4,5,'new']
    })

for colNames in df_sam.columns:
    for lenDf in range(len(df_sam[colNames])):
            if type(df_sam[colNames][lenDf]) == type(df_sam['a'][1]) and colNames == 'c':
                print(colNames, lenDf,df_sam[colNames][lenDf] )
```

If you want to automate just for last col,

```
import pandas as pd
df_sam = pd.DataFrame({
        'a' : ['rick','johnatthan','katei','diana','richard'],
        'b' : ['rich','roman','italy','ed','taylor'],
        'c' : [2,3,4,5,'new'],
        'd': [2, 3, 4, 5, 'dnew']
    })
lenOfColNames = len(df_sam.columns)
counter = 0
for colNames in df_sam.columns:
    counter = counter + 1
    for lenDf in range(len(df_sam[colNames])):
            if type(df_sam[colNames][lenDf]) == type(df_sam['a'][1]) and counter == lenOfColNames:
                print(colNames, lenDf,df_sam[colNames][lenDf] )
```